# With VCL Styles TProgressBar.Style := pbstMarquee does not work

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

When I use `pbstMarquee` on progress bar control with VCL Styles, marquee animation does not work.

Steps to reproduce:

1. File > New > VCL Application
2. Put `TProgressBar` on main form > `TProgressBar.Style := pbstMarquee`
3. Project Option >  Appearence > set Custom Style > set Default Style
4. Ctrl + F9

How to solve this problem and show animation with VCL Styles?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a feature not implemented in the [TProgressBarStyleHook](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TProgressBarStyleHook). Unfortunally Windows does not send any message to the progress bar control to indicate if the position of the bar changes when is in [marquee mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#PBS_MARQUEE), so you must implement your self a mechanism to mimic the PBS_MARQUEE Style, this can be easily done creating a new style hook and using a [TTimer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TTimer) inside of the style hook.

Check this basic implementation of the Style hook

```
uses
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Themes,
  Winapi.CommCtrl;

{$R *.dfm}

type
 TProgressBarStyleHookMarquee=class(TProgressBarStyleHook)
   private
    Timer : TTimer;
    FStep : Integer;
    procedure TimerAction(Sender: TObject);
   protected
    procedure PaintBar(Canvas: TCanvas); override;
   public
    constructor Create(AControl: TWinControl); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
 end;


constructor TProgressBarStyleHookMarquee.Create(AControl: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited;
  FStep:=0;
  Timer := TTimer.Create(nil);
  Timer.Interval := 100;//TProgressBar(Control).MarqueeInterval;
  Timer.OnTimer := TimerAction;
  Timer.Enabled := TProgressBar(Control).Style=pbstMarquee;
end;

destructor TProgressBarStyleHookMarquee.Destroy;
begin
  Timer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TProgressBarStyleHookMarquee.PaintBar(Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  FillR, R: TRect;
  W, Pos: Integer;
  Details: TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  if (TProgressBar(Control).Style=pbstMarquee) and StyleServices.Available  then
  begin        
    R := BarRect;
    InflateRect(R, -1, -1);
    if Orientation = pbHorizontal then
      W := R.Width
    else
      W := R.Height;

    Pos := Round(W * 0.1);
    FillR := R;
    if Orientation = pbHorizontal then
    begin
      FillR.Right := FillR.Left + Pos;
      Details := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tpChunk);
    end
    else
    begin
      FillR.Top := FillR.Bottom - Pos;
      Details := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tpChunkVert);
    end;

    FillR.SetLocation(FStep*FillR.Width, FillR.Top);
    StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, Details, FillR);
    Inc(FStep,1);
    if FStep mod 10=0 then
     FStep:=0;
  end
  else
  inherited;
end;

procedure TProgressBarStyleHookMarquee.TimerAction(Sender: TObject);
var
  Canvas: TCanvas;
begin
  if StyleServices.Available and (TProgressBar(Control).Style=pbstMarquee) and Control.Visible  then
  begin
    Canvas := TCanvas.Create;
    try
      Canvas.Handle := GetWindowDC(Control.Handle);
      PaintFrame(Canvas);
      PaintBar(Canvas);
    finally
      ReleaseDC(Handle, Canvas.Handle);
      Canvas.Handle := 0;
      Canvas.Free;
    end;
  end
  else
  Timer.Enabled := False;
end;

initialization

TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TProgressBar, TProgressBarStyleHookMarquee);

end.
```

You can check a demo of this style hook [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12733424/Blog/PbMarquee/PbMarquee.html)