# How i can use the native progressbar when the vcl styles are enabled?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I need use a progress bar  with the *pbstMarquee* style, I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861136/is-vclstyle-bug-tprogressbar-style-pbstmarquee-does-not-work) and the accepted answer works fine, but now i need draw the native progress bar

[image]

How i can use the native progressbar when the vcl styles are enabled?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just assign the default vcl style hook [`TStyleHook`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook)  to the [`TProgressBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TProgressBar) component and in that way the progress bar will be draw with the Windows look and feel.

```
 TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TProgressBar, TStyleHook);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delphi: `Form1.ProgressBar1.StyleElements := [seClient, seBorder, seFont];`

C++: `Form1->ProgressBar1->StyleElements = TStyleElements();`